# How to change Text Color and Text Size with Java in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, textview, textcolor

```
package com.example.androidx;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void setXiaomiPhone(View view) {
        TextView helloTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        helloTextView.setText("Hello Xiaomi Phone");
   }
}
```

I need to change the text in Text View, and I also need to change the color and the size of the text. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the text color:

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.<name_of_color>));
```

To change the text size:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);
```

Comment: 1. Rename textView to helloTextView . 2. Import ContextCompat 3. Replace context with  this . 4. Add  one color in colors.xml and provide the name in place of <name_of_color>

Comment: Hey Swayangit, perhaps you can tell what I should do next for changing the color https://prnt.sc/puz8b8

Comment: 1. Create one entry in colors.xml   <color name="color_name">#3FC5F0</color>

Comment: I created an entry for my color in colors.xml https://prnt.sc/puzkuo

Comment: ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorBlue);

Comment: one more bug, don't know how to solve it https://prnt.sc/puznew

Comment: thats   "this,"    not " this."

Comment: still have some bug with the code, do you know how to solve this error? https://prnt.sc/puzy7j

Comment: Add one bracket at the end.

Comment: thanks man, it helped. the color is changed. as I talked. i want to change my color anr text size. I entered your code in my project and it showed such a bug https://prnt.sc/pv0934

Comment: import TypedValue

Comment: made this step but the code is not working. can you help? https://prnt.sc/pv0gy3

Comment: helloTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);

Comment: thanks man! it finally worked for me. i've accepted the answer as it was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
helloTextView.setTextColor
(Color.parseColor("#hex code"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To change color, write

```
helloTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

To change size,

```
helloTextView.setTextSize(14.0f);
```

You can put your dersired values, such as *Color.GREEN* or *15.0f*